# Divisibility of multinomial by a prime number

Tags: combinatorics, prime-numbers, divisibility, multinomial-coefficients

What is the condition for divisibility of multinomial $ \dbinom {n}{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k} $ by a prime $p$?

**Update:**

I tried to solve using a generalisation of Lucas Theorem by representing the $n$ as well as $x_1, x_2,\dots,x_k$ in base $p$ representation. 
I am following this site - 
[Editorial to a problem](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/4176/term-editorial)

I am stuck on the part where it says that "..to be non-zero modulo p, it has to satisfy $n_j$ = $\Sigma{x_{i_j}}$ for all j..."

Comment: You want a finite number at the bottom ($x_1$ to $x_n$), right? I've made that assumption in my edit. Anyway, you should tell us your ideas/thoughts first.

Comment: It reduces to the same question about binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{x_i}$, because $p$ divides the multinomial coefficient iff it divides one of the $\binom{n}{x_i}$.

Comment: @AhaanRungta edit done

Answer (score 3):

A multinomial coefficient can be expressed using the binomial ones:
$${{n}\choose{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k}}={{n}\choose{x_1}}{{n-x_1}\choose{x_2}}{{n-x_1-x_2}\choose{x_3}}\ldots{{n-x_1-x_2-\ldots-x_{k-2}}\choose{x_{k-1}}}$$
Since a product is divisible by $p$ if and only if at least one of the factors is divisible by $p$, one can apply any of the divisibility criteria for binomials to obtain the answer for multinomials too.

The value of the multinomial doesn't depend on the order of $x_1, \ldots, x_k$ values in its "denominator", allowing them to be rearranged arbitrarily. Thus, it's actually sufficient to check the divisibility of ${{n}\choose{x_i}}$ for $1\leq i\leq k$.

---

Alternatively, one can take the definition of a multinomial coefficient
$${{n}\choose{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k}} = \frac{n!}{x_1!x_2!\ldots x_k!}$$
and calculate the [$p$-adic valuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_valuation) of numerator and denominator directly using the equality:
$$v_p(n!)=\sum_{i\geq 1} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^i}\right\rfloor$$

The coefficient will then be divisible by $p$ if and only if $v_p(n!)>v_p(x_1!)+v_p(x_2!)+\ldots+v_p(x_k!)$

Comment: Nice approach . But i was looking for a solution through lucas theorem.

Comment: I especially like the alternative approach. It suits my application computationally if I store values for $v_p(n!)$ in a cache.